# Harry Potter fanfic with an item called "death orb" (or something along those lines)

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

A long while ago I read yet another fanfic. I don't remember much about it though.

- It was definitely an M or at least PG (T, teen) rated fic, had time travel or was travel to another universe.
- I think Voldemort traveled with Harry.
- It had an item called "death orb" or something along those lines that was supposed to be banned and destroyed. They were used on prisoners before getting kissed I think or before the Dementors were used in prison.
- Harry had some kind of scarring mark from that orb or such, I think in his neck as a branding.
- Harry had Voldemort as his Boggart, chanting with the orb.
- I think Luna dies in his arms. Pretty sure he also digs her grave.
- He was captured and kept in Voldemort's care for a few weeks or months.
- Pretty sure it was on Fanfiction.net.
- I think it had Remus and Sirius in it as well.
- When asked what that (the boggart) had been, Harry says it was Voldemort.

Ach, I've read so many that I'm not sure if all of this is in one fic or not. I hope someone can tell me what they think the fic might be though.

Comment: [All the death orbs on fanfiction.net](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl%3Awww.fanfiction.net%2F%20%22death%20orb%22)

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5792220/20/Dark-Angel

Comment: Can you remember anything else? Also, are you sure it is a "death orb"?

Comment: I know it was an object that had "death" in it, and I'm pretty sure it was an orb

Comment: Can you recall any words that were used that were especially unique? You've mentioned a 'branding', for example. Was it a "branding" or a "brand" or was he "branded"?

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/u/1095936/Guardian-of-Hope - Orb of Doom, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Found it! ["Harry Potter and the Difference of Time"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4253051/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Difference-of-Time) It was [death sphere](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4253051/20/Harry-Potter-and-the-Difference-of-Time) not orb!

> Harry Potter’s life has been an incredible journey, but his death will be even more incredible. Harry Potter dies and is sent back in time to rewrite his history. What will he change? How will he cope?

Comment: Very nice! You can accept your own answer after two days.